# Term for a polygamist's wife

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, kinship-terms

Is there a term for a wife of a polygamist if she has *only* one spouse?

Comment: What's wrong with *wife*?

Comment: *Good at sharing..?* hehe.. I suppose she would just be a monogamist married to a polygamist. Or maybe.. W.O.P. (You heard it here first ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In describing the relationship between the wives of a polygamist, the term *[co-wife](http://www.wordnik.com/words/co-wife)* is often used.

Comment: The term *slave* is also often used, especially as the number of wives increases.

Answer (score 1):

In both older China and modern West Africa, I have heard the first woman married addressed as "First Wife" or "Head Wife."

For a 1991 Chinese movie set in the 1920s, see [Raise the Red Lantern](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101640/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), where you will hear this kind of address.

Using an ordinal number plus "Wife" is also used in [Islam](http://www.polyganyfirstwife.com/) and [Mormonism](http://www.exmormon.org/mormwomn.htm).